# TERADATA: query optimization

Tags: sql, teradata, query-performance

This query is working but it seems to take longer time than usual to retrieve the data.  Is there a better solution to optimize this query?  I need to get all PRD_ID from T1 and T2 even if there is no match with S1 and S2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.PRD_ID T.AMOUNT, T.DATE, T.REGION
FROM
(

       SELECT DISTINCT T1.PRD_ID, T1.PRD_CODE, S1.ORDER_DATE AS DATE, T1.REGION
       FROM
        (

               (SELECT  PRD_ID, PRD_CODE,AMOUNT,REGION
                FROM PRODUCT
                WHERE REGION='CA') T1

                LEFT JOIN SERVICE_1    S1  
                ON  S1.PRD_ID = T1.PRD_ID
                AND S1.PRD_CODE= T1.PRD_CODE
                AND S1.AMT = T1.AMOUNT
                AND S1.ORDER_DATE >= '01/01/2015' 
                AND S1.ORDER_DATE <= '02/28/2015'
        ) 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT T2.PRD_ID, T2.PRD_CODE, S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT AS DATE, T2.REGION
        FROM
         (

               (SELECT  PRD_ID, PRD_CODE,AMOUNT,REGION
                FROM PRODUCT
                WHERE REGION='IL') T2

                LEFT JOIN SERVICE_2   S2 
                ON  S2.PRD_ID = T2.PRD_ID
                AND S2.PRD_CODE= T2.PRD_CODE
                AND S2.AMT = T2.AMOUNT
                AND S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT >= '20150101'
                AND S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT <= '20150228'
        )
) T
ORDER BY REGION, ORDER_DATE DESC, PRD_ID
```

Comment: Teradata in the title but tagged with MySQL?  What database are you using?

Comment: If you change that UNION ALL to a UNION the subquery itself will be only distinct PRD_ID, AMOUNT, DATE, and REGION, so you can remove the DISTINCT from the outside query.

Comment: This is teradata but I saw it was suggested to tag in MySQL.  I think they are very similar.

Comment: @angelcake Teradata and MySQL are not similar in any way except they execute sql.

Comment: What are the dates formatted differently in the 1st and the 2nd part? What is the type of `SERVICE_1 . ORDER_DATE`?

Comment: I checked, both of their data type is "date".  For some reason if I used '20150101', '20150228' for order_date, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why you need all these (3!) levels of nested tables. The following should be equivalent:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        T1.PRD_ID, T1.PRD_CODE, S1.ORDER_DATE AS DATE, T1.REGION
    FROM
        PRODUCT    T1
        LEFT JOIN SERVICE_1    S1  
            ON  S1.PRD_ID = T1.PRD_ID
            AND S1.PRD_CODE= T1.PRD_CODE
            AND S1.AMT = T1.AMOUNT
            AND S1.ORDER_DATE >= DATE '2015-01-01'   -- converted '01/01/2015' 
            AND S1.ORDER_DATE <= DATE '2015-02-28'   -- converted '02/28/2015'
    WHERE T1.REGION = 'CA'

UNION ALL                  -- No need for DISTINCT here. The Region
                           -- is different between the 2 parts.
    SELECT DISTINCT
        T2.PRD_ID, T2.PRD_CODE, S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT AS DATE, T2.REGION
    FROM 
        PRODUCT    T2
        LEFT JOIN SERVICE_2   S2 
            ON  S2.PRD_ID = T2.PRD_ID
            AND S2.PRD_CODE= T2.PRD_CODE
            AND S2.AMT = T2.AMOUNT
            AND S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT >= DATE '2015-01-01'
            AND S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT <= DATE '2015-02-28'
    WHERE T2.REGION = 'IL'

ORDER BY REGION, DATE DESC, PRD_ID ;
```

or:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        T1.PRD_ID, T1.PRD_CODE, S1.ORDER_DATE AS DATE, 'CA' AS REGION
    FROM
        ( SELECT  PRD_ID, PRD_CODE, AMOUNT
          FROM PRODUCT
          WHERE REGION = 'CA'
        )    T1
        LEFT JOIN SERVICE_1    S1  
            ON  S1.PRD_ID = T1.PRD_ID
            AND S1.PRD_CODE= T1.PRD_CODE
            AND S1.AMT = T1.AMOUNT
            AND S1.ORDER_DATE >= DATE '2015-01-01'  
            AND S1.ORDER_DATE <= DATE '2015-02-28'  

UNION ALL 

    SELECT DISTINCT
        T2.PRD_ID, T2.PRD_CODE, S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT AS DATE, 'IL' AS REGION
    FROM 
        ( SELECT  PRD_ID, PRD_CODE, AMOUNT
          FROM PRODUCT
          WHERE REGION = 'IL'
        )    T2
        LEFT JOIN SERVICE_2   S2 
            ON  S2.PRD_ID = T2.PRD_ID
            AND S2.PRD_CODE= T2.PRD_CODE
            AND S2.AMT = T2.AMOUNT
            AND S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT >= DATE '2015-01-01'
            AND S2.ACCT_CALENDAR_DT <= DATE '2015-02-28'

ORDER BY REGION, DATE DESC, PRD_ID ;
```

Comment: This query works great except I have encounter two issues.  1. I got an error "The ORDER BY" clause must contain only integer constants."  What does it mean?  2.  The 2nd query gives me "no more spool space" even though there are only 5 records matched. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try using `ORDER BY 4, 3 DESC, 1 ;` instead. I don't have Teradata so I can't test. And what do you mean by "2nd query"? I only wrote 1 query.

Comment: About the dates, if the columns are of `date` type, either `'20150228'` or `'2015-02-28'` should work. Test or consult the Teardata docs.

Comment: The 2nd query I referred to is the 2nd SELECT after union all for the region "IL".  I tested my original query for "IL" only, It doesn't give me no more spool space error, but the query you suggested for "IL" gives me this error eve though I think your query is more efficient. The date return for "IL" is null, is it because of the null causing spool error?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Teradata errors or optimization. I only suggested an obvious rewriting/simplification. You could try keeping the `(SELECT  PRD_ID, PRD_CODE,AMOUNT,REGION FROM PRODUCT WHERE REGION='IL') T2` subquery.

Comment: I recreated "PRODUCT" table (which is a volatile table on teradata) with index and it resolves the no more space issue.  And by using 4,3 DESC, 1 as you suggested for order by also resolve the order by issue I had earlier.  Thanks so much for the help on optimizing query!

Comment: The `4, 3, 1` numbers are the columns (as ordered in the SELECT list). It's an old SQL syntax that I thought no-one uses. I'm astonished that Teradata forces you to use that! (does it need it only for UNION queries?)